# retrive value from database using radio button in php and only displaying the field name which is selected not others

Tags: php, mysql

I think the answer to this question can be very simple but I'm not able to get the basic idea of getting my answer.

Context:

I made a simple page of booking movie ticket through radio button and able to store and retrieve value and after retrieving the value.

I have added radio button in that value and then tried to retrieve the value of single field in other page but the I only get one value displayed not other one.

The value for the first row in one table is only displayed and does not matter which value is selected.

Markup:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body bgcolor= cyan>
<form method="post" action="sqlmovie1.php">
<table cellpadding="20" cellspacing="40" bgcolor="red"width="100%"><center>
<tr>
<td> <center><font size=+5 color="MAGENTA">BOOK TICKET </FONT><center>
</td></tr></center>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<center>
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">
<tr><td>

audi1: <input type = "radio" name="audi" value="1">

audi2: <input type = "radio" name="audi" value="2">

audi3: <input type = "radio" name="audi" value="3">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><CENTER>
<input type="submit" value ="submit"></CENTER></td>
</tr>
</table>

</center>
</table>
</form>
</html>
</body>
```

php code is sqlmovie1.php

```
<?php
$cxn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","movie");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "invalid login :",$mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = $_POST['audi'];
echo "<html> <body> 
<table border='1'>
<tr><td> movie name </td>
<td> timing</td>
<td> ticket price </td>
<td> book movie </td> </tr>";

if(isset($name) && ($name =="1"))
{
    $sql="select * from  movie1";
    $result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
    $column_count = mysqli_num_fields($result);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!="")
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo("<tr>");
            for ($column_num = 0;$column_num < $column_count;$column_num++)
                echo "<TD>$row[$column_num]</TD>\n";
                echo "<td><form method='post' action ='moviebooked1.php'>  <input type ='radio' name = 'book1' value='1'></td><td><input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'book show'></form></td>";
                echo("</TR>\n");
         }    
    }

//echo "<form method='post' action='moviebooked1.php'>  <input type ='radio' name = 'book1' value='1'><input type='submit' name='submit' value= 'book show'></form>";
}
elseif(isset($name) && ($name=="2"))
{
    $sql="select * from  movie2";
    $result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
    $column_count = mysqli_num_fields($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!="")
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo("<TR ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>");
            for ($column_num = 0;$column_num < $column_count;$column_num++)
                echo("<TD>$row[$column_num]</TD>\n");
                echo "<td><form method='post' action ='moviebooked1.php'>  <input type ='radio' name = 'book2' value='2'></td><td><input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value ='book show'></form></td>";
            echo("</TR>\n");
        }
    }
}
elseif(isset($name) && ($name=="3"))
{
    $sql="select * from  movie3";
    $result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
    $column_count = mysqli_num_fields($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!="")
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo("<TR ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>");
            for ($column_num = 0;$column_num < $column_count;$column_num++)
                echo("<TD>$row[$column_num]</TD>\n");
                echo "<td><form method='post' action ='moviebooked1.php'>  <input type ='radio' name = 'book3' value='3'></td><td><input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'book show'></form></td>";
                echo("</TR>\n");

        }
    }
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I applied different methods in the table `movie1 movie2` and `movie3` but didn't got anything new and problem lies here and above code.

In `movie1`,

I stored 3 rows `moviename, movietiming` and `ticketprice`,

Values are `row1 is kick 11.00am 150`, `row2 is hulk 12.00pm 150` `row3 is fastandfurious 1pm 150`.

If I try to retrive the answer the name of the movie for which I booked, its not giving me the correct movie name it only displays the name of first movie in all the table.

I'm booking through the radio button. How can I get my right movie name which I selected

Aa big tnx in advance for the help, problem is very very small but question is big.

Here is my last code `moviebooked1.php`:

```
<?php
$cxn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","movie");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "invalid login :",$mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_POST['book1']))
{
$sql="select moviename from movie1";
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
foreach($row as $value['moviename'])
{
echo " your show for ,$row['moviename'],"has been booked";}

}}

elseif (isset($_POST['book2']))
{
$sql="select moviename from movie2";
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
if($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "your ticket for",  $row['moviename'], "movie has been booked";
echo "<br>";
}
if (isset($_POST['book3']))
{
$sql="select moviename from movie3";
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "your ticket for",  $row['moviename'], "movie has been booked";
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it getting stored in the database correctly?

Comment: You also have some arrows in the last bit of code you put in, You combine php using "." not "," so it should say `echo "your show for ".$row['moviename']." has been booked";`

Comment: yes m able to store it in the database correctly............... i also tried it . and , both but not working when you will store 3 rows in each table u will definitely will get the exact problem......there u can see only the value for first row will b displayed

Comment: Can you post the contents of the database table? Also: Why are you using 3 different tables?

Comment: also, how many <td> tags are being echo'd? Specifically this part `echo("<TD>$row[$column_num]</TD>\n");` Are you receiving the same content in each td tag? Or is there only 1 td tag?

Comment: m again explaining look i made 1 database name movie there i created 3 tables named as movie1 , movie2 and movie3 .........all 3 table have same 3 columns name moviename movietiming and ticketprice ......when i inserted 3 records with different movie name in one table as mentioned above i was able to insert it then in mysqlmovie1.php page i retrived my record and simply added the radion button in front of each record and when i select one of theese record it doesnot display me with right movie name only first moviename is displayed ...

Comment: .if u will try the code and will make run on ur side u will kno the exact prob ....... code in movieform.php is just the form ....sqlmovie1.php display the data from the database and at the same time i added the radio button in it.....in moviebooked1.php m getting the issue only the first record is displayed if i try to display the second record it again display the first record....

Comment: I have trouble following your code and your writing, sorry. I asked you how many `<td>` tags were being echo'd on the page so that I could have a better understanding as to what all is being sent from your table. I can clearly see your code and know what it looks like on the page. Another problem I am having is understanding why you have 3 tables that are all duplicates, when you could have included all the content into one and sort by a field that had values "movie1, movie2, or movie3"